# Laravel filtering Route:when on sub collection

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add a filter using Route:when on a sub collection but it's not firing off.

Here is the example

URL

```
www.domain.com/firstcollection/id/subcollection
```

Working Route when on first collection

```
Route::when('firstcollection/*', 'auth_token', array('put')); 
www.domain.com/firstcollection
```

But when I try to user Route:when on a sub collection the filter doesn't fire off

```
Route::when('firstcollection/{id}/subcollection/*', 'auth_token', array('post'));
www.domain.com/firstcollection/id/subcollection
```

below is the full code

```
Route::filter('auth_token', function(){
//some logic here
}); 

Route::when('firstcollection/*', 'auth_token', array('put')); 
Route::when('firstcollection/{id}/subcollection/*', 'auth_token', array('post'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the two routes around. Otherwise the first wild card is capturing the second route as well

```
Route::when('firstcollection/{id}/subcollection/*', 'auth_token', array('post'));
Route::when('firstcollection/*', 'auth_token', array('put'));
```

Also - I dont think you can use {id} on a "when" clause. The system is looking for an actualy url of firstcollection/{id}/subcollection - which wont work. But since you are using post and put - this would work.

```
Route::when('firstcollection/*', 'auth_token', array('post, put'));
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Same result. I have even removed the firstcollection Route:When.

Comment: Are you using the 'put' method on your form to allow it to even hit the route?

Comment: I am using the "POST" method on the subcollection

Comment: Post your form in your question.

Comment: Your form code - not the form itself. Show me where/how you do Form::open()

Comment: I'm building a RESTful API application so there isn't a form. I am using a RESTclient to test all the request. I have set the method to POST